# Mysql Group by/Order by private messages list

Tags: mysql

Table structure

```
Id      User_From        User_To       Time_sent          Message       Message_read
1               1              2       ~TimeLast         ~Message                  0
2               3              2           ~Time             ...                   0
3               3              2       ~TimeLast             ...                   0
```

How would I create a query that filters out all the unread messages but only shows the last one of them if more than 1 unread mes are in the table?

So Id get this as a result

```
Id    User_From      User_To     Time_sent       Message       Mesage_read
 1            1            2      LastTime            ~~                 0
 3            3            2      LastTime            ~~                 0
```

Edit : this worked fine

```
select p.id,user_from,username,message,time_sent,message_read 
    from private_messages p join users u on p.user_from = u.id where p.id in (select max(id) as id from private_messages where user_to = :u1 group by user_from
```

Answer (score 0):

So your result should only always give back one message? And this one message should be the last one sent? then this query would work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Message_read 0 
ORDER BY Time_sent LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Does it state one message in my wanted result? NO

Answer (score 0):

it is simple using Mysql LIMIT, "Mysql Limit" can define how many results you will get, for example if you use "LIMIT 1" in your mysql query then you will get only 1 result.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Message_read=0 
ORDER BY Time_sent LIMIT 1
```

This should only return 1 result from table where Message_read=0 and that is latest in your table.